# Access to ftp image with wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, widget

I want to get files (images) in my folder on a ftp in my wordpress site.

How can i do that ?

My path to files on ftp : "/public_html/wp-content/uploads/image.png"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you need to use FTP? Are you getting the images from a different website you mean?

Comment: if i add with the image manager of wordpress, it goes to the database no ?
how can you take the image src if it is on the ftp or if it is with the wordpress manager ?

Comment: No, the file is stored in the uploads folder. The location of the file is stored in the database

Comment: ok perfect then. how do you get the file path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want WordPress to use the images, you'll have to upload them through the media uploadr. otherwise, you'll have images but no Database associations. I'd strongly advice against an FTP upload.

Comment: Is it correct to put in my folder "uploads" my image with a FTP ?
For exemple: path could be http://localhost/SpinMove/wp-content/uploads/imagetest.png

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer